# mapping one-to-many relation with Fluent NHibernate does not contain any child when browsing through one-end

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, bidirectional

I've created the following domain classes:

```
public class Car
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Registration { get; set; }
    public virtual User ResponsibleContact { get; set; }

    protected Car()
    {}

    public Fahrzeug(User responsibleContact, string registration)
    {
        ResponsibleContact = responsibleContact;
        Registration = registration;

        ResponsibleContact.Cars.Add(this);
    }
}

public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] EncryptedUsername { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] EncryptedPassword { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Car> Cars { get; private set; }

    public virtual string Username
    {
        get
        {
            var decrypter = UnityContainerProvider.GetInstance().UnityContainer.Resolve<IRijndaelCrypting>();
            return decrypter.DecryptString(EncryptedUsername);
        }
    }

    protected User()
    { }

    public User(byte[] encryptedUser, byte[] encryptedPassword)
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>();
        EncryptedUsername = encryptedUser;
        EncryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
    }
}
```

and the mapping classes:

```
public class CarMap : ClassMap<Car>
{
    public CarMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(c => c.Registration);

        References(c => c.ResponsibleContact).Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(st => st.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(st => st.EncryptedUsername).Column("Username");
        Map(st => st.EncryptedPassword).Column("Password");
        HasMany(st => st.Cars).Inverse().AsBag();
    }
}
```

If I query some Member objects, I get the members, but the cars collection is empty! 
If I query some Cars I got all the cars with the right Member. But within the member, the cars collection is also empty!

Is there anybody who has an Idea of what can happened?

Answer (score 1):

you have to make sure the foreign key column of the collection and the reference is the same otherwise there is a mismatch.

```
References(c => c.ResponsibleContact, "ResponsibleContact_id").Not.Nullable();
```

and

```
HasMany(st => st.Cars).Inverse().KeyColumn("ResponsibleContact_id");
```